# How to define an input to save float in Easy admin?

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

I'm on Symfony 4. I would save a decimal entry and Easy admin say "This value must be string", it generate a text input in the HTML.

I tried to not change the type and set the type to number too. I tried too to set the scale option to "force" the type but it continue to ask me a string...

easy_admin.yaml

```
- { property: 'points', label: 'BO.label.points', type: 'number' }
```

Property of my entity

```php
    /**
     * @var float|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=false, precision=12, scale=3, options={"default":0})
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    private $points;
```

I would to save my value. When I write 3, it's not okay because Easy Admin is waiting a pure string.

EDIT : I added these options to my number type :

```
- { property: 'points', label: 'BO.label.points', type: 'number', type_options: { html5: true, input: 'number' }}
```

Anyway, Easy Admin always asks a string. Any idea ?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: In the "type" property for easy_admin.yaml, I don't even see a `"number"` option in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#customize-the-properties-appearance). Have you tried setting to `'decimal'` to match your entity?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's for the form type to add or edit my entity. I used the decimal type to show my element in the listing. For the form, I believe it uses exactly the same types than Symfony. I get an error with the "decimal" type. Already tried "number" for the "NumberType" in Symfony 4, but it doensn't work when I want to save it.

Comment: I saw I had these options for number type :  
- { property: 'points', label: 'BO.label.points', type: 'number', type_options: { html5: true, input: 'number' }}

But easy admin asks always a string. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's okay if I "override" the default constraint in the entity.

If I write my property like this :

```php
    /**
     * @var float|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=false, precision=12, scale=3, options={"default":0})
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message = "The value {{ value }} must be of type {{ type }}")
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    private $points;
```

So, my value is saved correctly when I specify an Assert\Type with the float type.

I hope it will be helpful for someone else.